# Правильно ли написано? Или надо писать "не зима, не осень, не весна"?

Tags: орфография

Заметьте, ни зима, ни осень, ни весна, а именно лето.

Comment: Тут важен контекст, а он, как затем пояснила сама Наталья, выгладит так: **Есть известная фраза: "Лето - это маленькая жизнь." Заметьте, н(е,и) зима, н(е,и) весна, н(е,и) осень, а именно лето.**  В таком контексте надо писать **"не"**.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае частица несёт смысл отрицания, поэтому писать надо **"не"**. Что становится совсем очевидно, если упростить до предела:

*Не зима, а лето.*

Вас ввёл в заблуждение тот факт, что часто можно встретить что-то вроде:

*Ни зима, ни осень, ни весна облегчения не принесли.*

В данном случае для отрицания имеется частица "не", а "ни" только усиливают эффект. В то же время, иногда "не" опущено, а "ни" продолжает играть прежнюю роль.

*- Где-нибудь его видели?

- Куда там... Ни дома, ни на работе.*

В ответе подразумевается "не видели". Но, опять же, в Вашем случае опущенного отрицания не наблюдается. Зато имеется противопоставление.

Последнее на тему:

Заметьте, не зима, не осень, не весна, а именно лето были ему по душе.
Заметьте, ни зима, ни осень, ни весна его не радовали, одно лишь только лето.

Answer (score 1):

Заметьте, ни зима, ни осень, ни весна, а именно лето.

Здесь для выбора НЕ/НИ **нужен полный текст**, так как смысл фразы неясен.

Можно домыслить так: Заметьте, **ни одно другое время года** (ни зима, ни осень, ни весна) не волнует его, а именно лето. Тогда НИ имеет усилительное значение.

**Сравнить:** "Безвременье ― ни осень, ни зима, Душевная распутица и слякоть!"  Здесь тоже усилительное значение: ни то ни сё. Но можно написать: У нас не зима и не осень: холодно, слякотно. Здесь важна и семантика, и структура предложения, и авторская позиция.

Comment: В контексте так: "Есть известная фраза: "Лето-это маленькая жизнь." Заметьте, н(е,и) зима, н(е,и) весна, н(е,и) осень, а именно лето." Как правильно не или ни?

Comment: Здесь отрицательная частица НЕ, отрицается каждое время года в отдельности.